# Rule of derivation of composite functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

The capacity of a signal is given by $C$

$$
C(S,N) = 7\ln(1+S/N)
$$

Supposing $S$ and $N$ are :

$$
S(t) = 4 + \cos(4\pi t)
$$

$$
N(t) = 2 + \sin(2\pi t)
$$

What is the rate of change of the channel capacity, as a function of time ?

Do I need to use the rule of derivation of composite functions, which is :
$$
\frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{dC}{dS} \cdot \frac{dS}{dt} +\frac{dC}{dN} \cdot \frac{dN}{dt} 
$$

It would give me
$$
\frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{7}{S+N} \cdot(-4\pi \sin(4\pi t)) +\frac{-7S}{N(N+S)} \cdot 2\pi \cos(2\pi t) 
$$

or I juste have to replace S and N in the first equation like this :
$$
C(t) = 7\ln\left(1+\frac{4 + \cos(4\pi t)}{2 + \sin(2\pi t)}\right)
$$

and to find the rate change I could derivate this equation

Could someone tell me if I'm thinking wrong?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C(S(t),N(t)) = 7\ln\left(1+\frac{S}{N}\right)$$
Differentiate it with respect to $t$. Denote $\frac{d}{dt}(\dots)\to(\dots)'$
$$
C^{'}=\frac{7}{1+\frac{S}{N}}\left(\frac{S^{'}}{N}-\frac{SN^{'}}{N^2}\right)=\frac{7}{N(N+S)}(S^{'}N-N^{'}S)
$$
Given that:
$$
\begin{array}
&S(t) = 4 + \cos(4\pi t)\\
N(t)=2+\sin(2\pi t)
\end{array}\to
\begin{array}
&S^{'} = -4\pi\sin(4\pi t)\\
N^{'}=2\pi\cos(2\pi t)
\end{array}
$$
Plug it to equation:
$$
C^{'}=7\frac{(-4\pi\sin(4\pi t)(2+\sin(2\pi t))-2\pi\cos(2\pi t)(4 + \cos(4\pi t)))}{(2+\sin(2\pi t))(6+\sin(2\pi t)+\cos(4\pi t))}
$$
With a little bit of work you can confirm that $\frac{d}{dt}C=\frac{d}{dt}\left(7\ln\left(1+\frac{4 + \cos(4\pi t)}{2 + \sin(2\pi t)}\right)\right)$, gives the same result as above, as it theoretically should do.

Comment: So my final answer for t=1 should be : $$
\frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{7}{5+2} \cdot(-4\pi \sin(4\pi 1)) +\frac{-7(5)}{2(2+5)} \cdot 2\pi \cos(2\pi 1) = -5 \pi 
$$ so my rate change is this answer?

Comment: @Pierre-LucBolduc: affirmative

Answer (score 1):

You will find both methods give the same answer.